# how to get back the results from HttpRequest inside a method

Tags: javascript, ajax, titanium, titanium-mobile

in my application i want to isolate the Networking in one method , its very common to fetch ajax in my app. so i've put the  Ti.Network.createHTTPClient() in a seperate method and i call it with a URL. then it will parse the JSON and return back the result. HOWEVER it always return back a null object.

i'm assuming it retched the end of the method before getting back from the .onload() method 
How can i solve that ?

```
function getJson(url)
{
Ti.API.info(" URL is " + url );
var jsonObject ; 
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.setTimeout(3000);
xhr.onload = function()
{
    var jsonObject = eval('(' + this.responseText + ')');

}
xhr.open("GET" , url); 
xhr.send(); 
Ti.API.info(" passed " );

return jsonObject; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a callback somewhere in your code like this :

```
function getJson(url,callback)
{
Ti.API.info(" URL is " + url );
var jsonObject ; 
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.setTimeout(3000);
xhr.onload = function()
{
    callback(jsonObject)

}
xhr.open("GET" , url); 
xhr.send(); 
Ti.API.info(" passed " );
};

function aCallBack(jsonObject){
// the code when the json returns
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a callback and give it to your function as a parameter; since it's asynchrone. Like so:

```
function getJson(url, callback) {
    // do your json-ajax stuff
    // where you get the response do:
    callback(response);
}
function callback(response) {
    // do whatever you like with the response
}
```